# Stress testing hardware

Tags: 10.04, hardware, testing

Is there a piece of software I can install on my Ubuntu installation (10.04) to stress test all the hardware on my computer?  I understand I can download a specific disto to do this, but I would prefer if I can simply download the software and use it on my current installation.

Comment: What kind of stress testing? Turning off the fan and see how long the machine stays powered on without burning?

Comment: To figure out why my computer keeps crashing after about 5 minutes after booting, even with a livecd.

Comment: you have log files for that ;)

Comment: btw start with memtest and check for faulty memory (you can choose to do this from the livecd during booting). Memory being the culprit of random crashes is more likely than anything else I guess.

Comment: might as well make it an answer. one moment.

Comment: @Rinzwind, where are the log files?

Comment: Logs you can view with `log viewer` or they are located in /var/log/ if you want to go commando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a well known option on the live cd where you can "stress" test your memory (fourth option in the menu):

[image]

This will have you end up into something similar to this:

[image]

This image actually is showing bad memory as you can see. If this shows up for you too you can assume those crashes to be caused by memory. If not please update your question ;)

Oh and checking memory can take up a lot of time. And when I say a lot I mean a lot ;)

Comment: Think in hours when reading "a lot time".

Comment: I've done a memtest and got the all clear.  Where do I find the logs.  In one of your comments you told me to check out the logs?

Answer (score 2):

## [Phoronix Test Suite](http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/) [image: Download phoronix-test-suite]

I never used it but I know that this is probably what you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

[stress test cpu on ubuntu](http://namhuy.net/1067/stress-test-cpu-on-ubuntu.html)

I have been using Prime95 on windows machines for a while, i found that cpuburn on ubuntu perform very similar to Prime95

To install cpuburn on ubuntu

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install cpuburn
```

You can use man to see more info about cpubun

```
# man cpuburn
```

To stress my cpu i run

```
# burnP6 &
# burnP6 &
# burnP6 &
# burnP6 &
```